# Random iframe content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to make an iframe on my website that loads a random URL from a list.
I tried this

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <iframe class="frame" src="" style="width:200px; height: 200px"></iframe>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   var cat1 = [
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XG_0iV2B40",
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnxpHIl5Ynw",
];

    var myFrame = document.getElementsByClassName("frame");

    function getRandomUrl(myFrame) {
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * cat1.length);
      var url = cat1[index];
      myFrame.src = url;
    }


    function codeAddress() {
      getRandomUrl(myFrame);
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    codeAddress();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

but it didn't work. I tried basically everything I could find, nothing worked and I don't understand why. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `it didn't work` - why? what happened instead?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("frame");` - returns a HTMLCollection ... try `document.getElementsByClassName("frame")[0];`

Comment: @JaromandaX I did that, still nothing, blank iframe

Comment: You need to use the YouTube 'embed' URL rather than the regular page link.  E.G.  `https://www.youtube.com/embed/__videoID__`

Comment: @BrianPeacock it still doesn't work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: `I did that, still nothing` looks like there's a video there now

Comment: @JaromandaX i switched to chrome, it works now, thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code has been edited with code from the answer, therefore there is nothing wrong with the code any more, making it a useless question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `document.getElementsByClassName("frame")`, which returns a **collection** of all of the elements with that class name. To access your specific frame, you need to access the first element with `document.getElementsByClassName("frame")[0]`.

In addition to this, you need to use YouTube's **embed** link (`https://www.youtube.com/embed/[videoID]`), rather than linking to the video directly through `?v=videoID`.

I've gone ahead and updated your links for you, corrected the variable, and logged the video source in the console. Clicking 'Run code snippet' multiple times will change the video randomly:

```js
var cat1 = [
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/8PIPyPMNnp8",
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/gM2KaaVXs_g",
];

var myFrame = document.getElementsByClassName("frame")[0];

function getRandomUrl(myFrame) {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * cat1.length);
  var url = cat1[index];
  myFrame.src = url;
}

function codeAddress() {
  getRandomUrl(myFrame);
}

codeAddress();

console.log(myFrame.src);
```

```html
<iframe class="frame" src="" style="width:200px; height: 200px"></iframe>
```

Hope this helps! :)